# Is this a possible approach to register .NET types for COM

Tags: .net, excel, vba, com, regasm

I have a .NET assembly and use regasm.exe to register for COM. The tlb is used by users to write code in VBA in Excel.

I did a regasm /regfile and I see that all registry entries are fallin in to 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\'.
I have an admin constraint (sadly) to run regasm on all user's machine since it requires admin access to write registry keys in to *HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*.

My question is, **if I change this to write to 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' or 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER', will the COM interop still work and will Excel be able to find my types ?**

This way, I am thinking I can negotiate for a much less previlieges to my users so they can run this new reg file rather than runing the regasm.

Thanks
Mani

Comment: Yes, COM searches HKCU first.  Why didn't you just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it's not so easy 'cause it depends on user settings, take a loot at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/06/06/per-user-com-registrations-and-elevated-processes-with-uac-on-windows-vista-sp1.aspx

Comment: This is interesting. But in my case I am using Win XP with SP3. Do you think this is still applicable ?

Comment: Yes and no, in Windows XP it works without troubles, you have to remember that "note" only for newer OS versions (at least warn your users or technical support service).

Comment: As the article states, when UAC is enabled and the account is running elevated, the per-user registration is ignored. However, this is a context where the per-machine registration will succeed.